# Failing a Kubernetes Deployment

Tags: kubernetes

I wonder if there is a way to have a deployment stop recreating new pods, when those failed multiple times. In other, given that we can't for instance have a restartPolicy never in a pod template of a Deployment, i am wondering, how can i consider a service failed and have in a stopped state.

We have a use case, where imperatively need to have kubernetes interrupt a deployment that have all his pods constantly failing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider using a type "Job" instead of Deployment. According to the docs:

> Use a Job for Pods that are expected to terminate, for example, batch
>   computations. Jobs are appropriate only for Pods with restartPolicy
>   equal to OnFailure or Never.

Hope this helps!

Comment: I think it is a fresh reminder. Here the expect to terminate will be, on failure basically. We expect our job to terminate when there is a serious failure. So a deployement is not meant to handle Task that mail fatally fail ?

Comment: I believe deployments are meant to be always running, so it will try to restart continuously with exponential backoff. You can try to specify the `.spec.progressDeadlineSeconds`, which will put the deployment controller into ProgressDeadlineExceeded state. For now (v1.13), it will keep retrying the deployment, but there are plans to allow it to do an automatic rollback for future releases.

Comment: Hey @FrankYuchengGu thank you I look into this but I thought it was just for updating the application or something like. That it working with rolling update. Could you a bit expand on this.

Comment: How can I actually use .spec.progressDeadlineSeconds and even .spec.minReadySeconds to actually control that process. What i want is that if the pods of the deployment keep restarting a lot, that at some point it get in that state ProgressDeadlineExceeded state. Can you explain the chain of reaction here and how to play with those parameter and maybe also confirm that you do not need to roll an update but simply an automatic restart on failure will trigger those parameter to be taken into account ?

Comment: Well if your pod encounters fatal error and crashes, the deployment controller will try to restart the pod. In this process, if the pod continuously crashes, then the minReadySeconds will timeout. From my understanding, there are no methods of having deployments stop restarting the pods. This is exponential backoff included in the deployment controller to prevent frequent starts of failed pods though. You can implement a Job controller that will just run the pod, and if it fails, it will exit.

Comment: I have just implemented what you suggested. However nothing is happening. minReadySeconds: 20 progressDeadlineSeconds: 60. But then running the command `kubectl get -n dev deployment triple-graph-builder -o yaml` and i don't see any ProgressDeadlineExceeded state

Comment: I guess maybe what you mean is eventually the replica set will have that state ProgressDeadlineExceeded state but it will not stop restarting things. So the solution is to use a job instead. However i would like to see that state happening just to see how it works. What is the command to see that status, because so far i do not see the status happening. I just scale it to 0 then back to 4, and we have the crash happening, but i do not see that status. My pod crash fast within the 20 seconds

Comment: Still weird, that there is no way to automatically stop a deployment that fails ....

Answer (score 1):

In my case I had a deployment that was in a fail and restart loop where the pod and its logs didn't stay around long enough for me to work out what had gone wrong.

As a workaround I temporarily changed the start up command so that even if the intended start up command failed the pod would be kept alive.  This allowed me to review the logs and remote into the container to work out what the issue was (I was using Kubernetes dashboard to view logs and remote into the machine).

Here is a simplistic example, imagine your deployment contains something like this (only key parts shown).

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
spec:
  template:
    spec:
       containers:
        - name: ...
          image: ...
          imagePullPolicy: ...
          ports:
            - name: http
              containerPort: ...
              protocol: TCP
          command:     
            - '/bin/sh'
            - '-c'
            - "(echo 'Starting up...' && exit 1 && tail -f /dev/null) || (echo 'Startup failed.' && tail -f /dev/null)"
          ....
```

I have bash shell installed in my docker container.  What happens here is it attempts to do everything in the brackets before the **double pipe "||"** and if that fails it will run everything after the double pipe.  So in the example case, "*Starting up*" will display, it will immediately "exit 1" which causes commands after the "||" to be run -  "*Startup failed.*" and a command to keep the container running.  I can then review the logs and remote in to run additional checks.